# empty list without empty word in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I am writing a recursion function returning an empty list in the base case. However the output of functions shows "empty" word in the my list, which I don't want.Like this;

> (list (list 'abc) (list 'def) empty (list 'ghi))

How can I prevent this? Thanks.

Comment: Please include your code so that we know what you are talking about.

Comment: It's also unclear what result you want. Include a test case, please.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is probably because Racket has several printing styles for values. Try changing it (in the language selection dialog) to "write" or whatever it's called, which should make it output `((abc) (def) () (ghi))` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The `empty` that you see in the result is not a "word" -- note that it's not quoted.  If you *do* expect an empty list in the result, then it looks like you got one.  You can even check for that:

```
> (empty? (third (list (list 'abc) (list 'def) empty (list 'ghi))))
#t
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing details, my best guess would be something like

```
(let ((result (recursive-call ...)))
(if (null? result) (resursive-call (cdr whatever-list))
(cons result (cdr whatever-list)))
```

Essentially, just check if the result is the empty list, and if so, don't put it into the list that you're returning.